# Defining byte arrray in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax, activex

How do I pass a byte array from JavaScript to an ActiveX control.

My JavaScript will call WCF server (method) and that method will return a byte array.
After that I need to pass this byte array to the ActiveX control.

Could anybody provide me a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by returning base64string rather than a byte array from the WCF Service.

So that i can simply convert the Base64 string usning Convert.FromBase64String() method to byte arrary.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what binding your WCF service uses (and as you are calling it from javascript I assume `webHttpBinding`) it is quite possible that the returned byte array will be returned as a base 64 encoded string. So you might need to modify the ActiveX component to accept a base 64 encoded string as parameter instead of a byte array.

Comment: hi Darin,

if i convert the base64 string to byte array 
using Convert.FromBase64String method

it is throwing an exception

invalid character in a base-64 string

Answer (score 0):

From javascript you will have a form of base64_encode string. ActiveX component should have a function to convert string to byte array like this

```
 byte[] string2byte(string s)
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[s.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 2) { b[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i, 2), 16); }
        return b;
    }
```